# Kendo MVVM binding 2 source in same remote template

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mvvm

I am using Kendo MVVM. This ApisTemplate is called Remotely and It opens up. Problem is in "PaxPreferenceTemplate" template. There are 2 source binding. Only 1st works i.e Segment . i dont know why . Even if you use

```
 <label data-bind:"text: Segment.SegmentDetailsToDisplayPricing" ></label>
```

still result would be same. if i comment

```
<div data-bind="source: Segment"></div>
```

then 2nd line works
    Please tell what would be correct way

Note: ALL below code is in 1 file.

```
<script id="ApisTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template" class="KendoExtTemplate">

    <div>
        <div data-bind="source: ApisVMList.PaxPreferenceBySegment" data-template="PaxPreferenceTemplate"></div>

        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" id="btnIssueTicket" onclick="SaveIssueTicket(this)" class="k-button k-primary Apis_submit " style="width: 100px; height: 25px; margin-right: 5px;">
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="k-button " onclick="CloseApisWindow(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>


<script id="PaxPreferenceTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template" class="KendoExtTemplate">

    <div data-bind="source: Segment" data-template="SegmentTemplate"></div>

    <div data-bind="source: PaxInfo" data-template="PaxInfoTemplate"></div>

</script>

<script id="SegmentTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template" class="KendoExtTemplate">
    <label data-bind="text: SegmentDetailsToDisplayPricing"></label>
</script>

<script id="PaxInfoTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template" class="KendoExtTemplate">
    <div>
        <label data-bind="text: Pax.PersonName"></label>
        <input data-role="dropdownlist"
               data-text-field="PassportNumber"
               data-value-field="PassportNumberID"
               data-bind="source: PossiblePassports" />

        <input data-role="dropdownlist"
               data-text-field="FrequentFlyernumber"
               data-value-field="FrequentFlyernumberID"
               data-bind="source: PossibleFrequentFlyers" />
    </div>



</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must to divide your template because you have two different type a list and a single item.

```
<script id="ApisTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template" class="KendoExtTemplate">

    <div>
        <div data-bind="source: ApisVMList.PaxPreferenceBySegment" data-template="PaxPreferenceTemplate"></div>
 <div data-bind="source: ApisVMList.PaxPreferenceBySegment" data-template="PaxPreferenceTemplate_Second"></div>

        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" id="btnIssueTicket" onclick="SaveIssueTicket(this)" class="k-button k-primary Apis_submit " style="width: 100px; height: 25px; margin-right: 5px;">
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="k-button " onclick="CloseApisWindow(this)" style="width: 100px; height: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="PaxPreferenceTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template" class="KendoExtTemplate">
    <div data-bind="source: Segment" data-template="SegmentTemplate"></div>
</script>
<script id="PaxPreferenceTemplate_Second" type="text/x-kendo-template" class="KendoExtTemplate">
    <div data-bind="source: PaxInfo" data-template="PaxInfoTemplate"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: The Object Source passed to PaxPreferenceTemplate is Collection of Array hence i need template . I cant delete PaxPreferenceTamplate and place code in parent html . Since then rendering wouldnt know PaxPreferenceBySegment[0] should be rendered or [1] etc.

The Object is of this structure:

https://jsfiddle.net/r9Lahs3f/

Comment: i have changed my response, and divide into two template.

Comment: Ciccio, there is problem when datasource 'ApisVMList.PaxPreferenceBySegment' has 2 items .  
  jsfiddle.net/9wduzvr1/2/

Comment: If your datasource is jsfiddle.net/r9Lahs3f is obvious that your rendering is not tree.
You have Segment and PaxInfo as the same root, but if you want PaxInfo as children of Segmnet you must to change your structure.

Comment: I dont know why 2 segment are generated at same time ? . Segment and PaxInfo are both same level under  PaxPreferenceBySegment . But please check UI which i want in this link jsfiddle.net/9wduzvr1/2/  . The UI link is there in html of jsfiddle . pls check . i want UI like that where arrow denotes in UI

Comment: The problem is not the UI, the problem is your structure, if you want that PaxInfo is even a child of Segment, you must to put it in the structure as children, if you take all in the same level, you will have in the ui all in the same level.

Comment: All are at same level. I have sent stringify json in fiddle link  jsfiddle.net/9wduzvr1/2/ .
 Thing is there are 2 segment in different obect of PaxPreference. Still both are iterating together. I dont know why

Comment: Do you know How to change value in kendo Dropdown MVVM ? I have multiple dropdown

Comment: Exist cascade property or you can use $("#dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(dataNew); for other question open new answer.

Comment: i want to change value not dataSource there are 4 dropdown like this.There are multiple frequent flyer dropdown.The condition is IF ONE OF THE DROPDOWN IS SELECTED THE VALUE SHOULD GET COPIED TO OTHER DROPDOWN IF OTHER FREQUENTFLYER DROPDOWN VALUE IS NULL. here is Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6g4fyjsy/

Comment: Open a question ;-)

Comment: i have reached my question asking limit. please help i need it

Comment: Your answer didnt provided me successful result